# Python - how to split a file object up into a list of individual characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm importing data from a file object. It's pretty simple; it's a .txt file, and the data was entered like this: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

I am trying to get it to be a list of individual characters, e.g.

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ...etc.]
```

but it's showing up like this:

```
my_list = ['ABCDEFGHIBJK... etc.]
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
def split(string): 
    return [char for char in string] 

# This opens a file, gets a file object, and returns it to the program.
def get_file_object1():
    infile = open(r'#', 'r')
    file_object = infile.readlines()

    testing = split(file_object)   # this is a test line
    print(testing)                 # this is a test line
    print(split('This is another test.'))

    infile.close()
    return file_object
```

Note: when I pass the file object to split(file_object), I get this

```
['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
```

But when I pass a string of text to split('This is another string.'), I get this:

```
['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', ' ',
 't', 'e', 's', 't', '.']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just read and apply `list()` ;-)

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Liz\Desktop\PYTHON PROBLEMS\cipherUpper.txt') as f:
  myList = list(f.read().strip())
```

Get `myList` as your list

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `readlines()` is list, so you're basically doing this:

```
string = ['ABC..', ...]
[char for char in string]
```

where char is equal to 'ABC..'

so you need to iterate over the result of readlines:

```
testing = []
for line in f.readlines():
    testing = testing + split(line)
```

or read a single line with `readline()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`split` is iterating the object it receives

When you pass `file_object`, the lines of the file are iterated. There is only one line so you receive the first line as a string.

```
testing = split(file_object)   # >> ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
```

When you pass a string, the characters of the string are iterated so you get a list of characters.

```
print(split('This is another test.')) # >> ['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ....
```